# Need an Explanation on this infinite series?

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone explain how this different infinite sum gives us the same result?
$$ \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{n}{2^n} =2 \ And\ \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{2^n} =2 $$

I know the second one is Geometric sum.

And is that possible to conclude for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{k^n} =\frac{k}{k-1}=\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{n}{k^n}$$
Thanks!

Comment: The two series you wrote are not equal. The former is clearly larger than the latter.

Comment: On the other hand, there is nothing strange in two different series adding up to the same sum: $3+1=2+2=4+0=\pi+\sqrt2+(4-\pi-\sqrt2)$.

Comment: You've messed up the geometric sum: note the sum starts at $n=1$, not $n=0$.

Comment: Andres: you are right but what about this $ 3+1=4+0=3+n \ where \ n \in \mathbb{N}$    it's like that $$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{n}{2^n}$  and  $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{2^n} $ are NOT equal.

$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{2^n} =2$ is false.

$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{2^n} =1$ is true.

If the term $n=0$ is not omitted :
 $\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{1}{2^n} =2$

$ \sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{n}{2^n}$  and  $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{2^n} $ are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series),  $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty r\cdot{a^r}=\frac1{\left(1-a\right)^2}$$ if $\displaystyle \left|a\right|<1$

$$\implies\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac r{2^r}=\frac12\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac r{2^{r-1}}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{\left(1-\dfrac12\right)^2}=2$$

and $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty{a^r}= \frac a{1-a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{n}} = \frac{1}{k}(1+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k^{2}}+...) = \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{1}{k-1},$ using geometric sum.